# Android - show info window (title) on cluster item click

Tags: android, google-maps

Having trouble understanding this problem.
I have a cluster renderer (OffersClusterRenderer) where

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(OffersMarker item,
                                           MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    int itemNumberOfOffers = item.getNrOfOffers();
    BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ro1);

    markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptor);
    markerOptions.snippet("Show");
    markerOptions.title("Show");
    super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
}
```

I also have ClusterManager and in my Activity I am running this:

```
rentClusterManager = new ClusterManager<OffersMarker>(this, gmap);
rentClusterManager.setRenderer(rentClusterRenderer);
```

My question is, how do show the info window (title) of the marker when onClusterItemClick is called?

Shouldn't it show by deafult? It says so in google docs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I managed to do that (this is Kotlin code, but you should understand it).
Add this method to your custom renderer:

```
internal fun showInfoWindow(marker: OffersMarker) {
    this.getMarker(marker).showInfoWindow()
}
```

And then in `onClusterItemClick(marker: OffersMarker)` add this line:

```
(mClusterManager.renderer as RentClusterRenderer).showInfoWindow(marker)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement method for onClusterItemClick which can be overrided in your activity.

Comment: I have that method, but what should it contain so that it will show me the title?

Comment: Have you set 
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager); ?

Comment: And you need to set placeVO.setTitle("your title");
and snippet placeVO.setSnippet("your snippet");

Comment: What is placeVO? I did the .title and .snipped inside the ClusterRenderer.onBeforeClusterItemRendered() method.

Answer (score 0):

@NilayDani is correct. You need to implement method for [`onClusterItemClick`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener.html). Its the triggering point to display info windows title.

An info window allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker. Only one info window is displayed at a time. If a user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed.

The simplest way to add an info window is to set the `title()` and `snippet()` methods of the corresponding marker. Setting these properties will cause an info window to appear whenever that marker is clicked.

Here's a sample code snippet how to display title including marker's position and snippet:

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .title("Melbourne")
                          .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
```

To view full code, check the demo code here: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos

Comment: Thanks but I have the .setTitle and .setSnippet in the ClusterRenderer.onBeforeClusterItemRendered() method.
I have also done Map.setOnMarkerClickListener().
The onClusterItemClickListener is working but no title is shown when clicked on marker.